# Read/Write/Delete to phone's internal/external memory using Android application?

Tags: android, security, mobile, network-security, security-testing

Is it possible to read/write/delete the data present in files or folders created by other applications? I am 99% sure that Android OS does not give such permission but to be 100% sure, I want to know this. The whole context is that if I download an Android app from an external source, what kind of security threats I may have?

Comment: You cannot modify files in internal memory of other apps. But all files in external memory you can read/modify delete for as long as they are not on removable media under kitkat.

Comment: Hi greenapps. Thanks for your comment. I assume that files like images, audio and video clips etc. are stored in external storage. So, is it possible for 3rd party apps to access those files? From your comment, it seems answer is Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to read/write/delete the data present in files or folders created by other applications?

That depends on where the "files or folders created by other applications" reside.

Files written by an app to its portion of [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) are not accessible by third-party apps in general. Users who root their devices can arrange to access those files.

Files written by an app to [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) are accessible by other apps and by the user, though the apps will need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

Files written by an app to its portion of [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), on Android 4.4+, are not accessible by third-party apps in general. Users will have access to these files, if not through Android apps, then by moving the media to some other hardware (e.g., notebook PC).

Files written by an app to removable media prior to Android 4.4 -- through undocumented and unsupported means -- are accessible by other apps, in addition to being accessible by the user.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. For example: WhatsApp saves all the Images in WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Images. So, is it possible that any third party application can access these images? As I understand WhatsApp folder is created automatically by WhatsApp application and resides in External storage.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKhurana: "So, is it possible that any third party application can access these images?" -- if they are on external storage, then yes.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be a security issue then!